# install ros as root, how to be used by other user

Tags: ros, root

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install ros and create the catkin_ws as a root, and use it for a long time.

Now I find that it is not good to install and run package as a root because sometimes package concerning with graphics interface does not work!

I do not know it as a ubuntu freshman, it is pretty embarrassing.

**So, how can I run ROS and use the package in catkin_ws I create as a other user?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248156/install-ros-as-root,-how-to-be-used-by-other-user/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Thanks to Patrick Goebel, the author of the book, ros by example.**

With my situation, I have to do below steps:

1, change to normal user

2, post-installation

3, move /root/catkin_ws to /home/NORMAL_USER

4, change the authority for /home/NORMAL-USER/catkin_ws

5,remove build/ and devel/ in the catkin_ws

6, rebuild your catkin_ws

7,add path to ~/.bashrc

8,source ~/.bashrc

**Here are part of detailed illustrations:**

2, after change to normal user ,as for my case, shawn. Reference to official tutorial [1.5 initiate rosdep and 1.6 environment setup](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#Initialize_rosdep)
, do post-installation step.

3,

```
sudo mv -a /root/catkin_ws /home/shawn/
```

4,

```
sudo chown -R shawn:shawn ~/catkin_ws
```

5,

```
~/catkin_ws$ rm -fr build devel
```

6,7,8

```
catkin_make
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) with karma: 339 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1